# How to break a bordermatrix into multiple matrices?

Tags: bordermatrix

I have a border matrix that is too large to fit on one page. I want to break it into multiple matrices.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Instead of `\bordermatrix` you might try `blockarray` from the `blkarray` package. If you have the code for the big single matrix, can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 3):

These are two possible solutions -- use of `blockarray` from blkarray package.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{blkarray,multirow}

\begin{document}

First solution

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc|ccc|c}
 &C_1& & \cdots & & C_k \\ 
 \begin{block}{c(c|ccc|c}
   A_1    & \multirow{3}{*}{$\vdots$} &  \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{$\ddots$}} 
&\multirow{3}{*}{$\vdots$} \\  
 \vdots  & & &  & & \\  
   A_n    & & & &  &    \\
\end{block}
\\
 &C_{k+1}&&\cdots& &C_m\\ 
 \begin{block}{cc|ccc|c)}
   A_1    & \multirow{3}{*}{$\vdots$} &  \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{$\ddots$}} 
&\multirow{3}{*}{$\vdots$} \\  
 \vdots  &   &  & &  &   \\  
   A_n   &   &  & &  &    \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

2nd solution

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc|ccc|c}
 &C_1&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&C_k\\ 
 \begin{block}{c(c|ccc|c}
   A_1    & \vdots  & \ddots &   \vrule         &          &  \vdots\\  
   \vdots & \vdots  &        &   \ddots         &          &  \vdots\\  
   A_n     & \vdots &        &   \vrule         & \ddots   &\vdots \\
\end{block}
\\
 &C_{k+1}&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&C_m\\ 
 \begin{block}{cc|ccc|c)}
   A_1    & \vdots  & \ddots    &    \vrule        &             &  \vdots\\  
   \vdots & \vdots  &           &    \ddots        &             &  \vdots\\  
   A_n     & \vdots &           &    \vrule        & \ddots      &\vdots \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```